# Reuse PIC serial pins

Tags: pic, bootloader, ftdi

I'm building a board with a PIC microcontroller that uses the **Microchip bootloader** and it's connected to a FT232RL chip (USB to UART) with the **RC7** and **RC6** lines.

**Is it possibile reuse these two I/O lines in the application firmware without problems?** Obviously without using jumpers in order to disconnect the FT232RL chip.

Comment: Not unless you can disable the TF232RL. The signal on your TX will go out on RS232. The RX coming from the UART will conflict with anything you tie it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from the PIC to the FT232 can be reused for any purpose you like, provided that you don't care that the signal is also going to the FT232 and hence to a connected PC.

The other signal is an output from the FT232, so if you want to re-use it you must 'isolate' the FT232 in some way. My favorite is a 1k resistor. If you use the PIC pin as output this will add some extra load. If you want to use the PIC pin as input there is a problem: the other source must be disabled while in bootload mode. I don't think this is worth the trouble.